# Universal analytics pageView with some hashtag

Tags: universal-analytics

I have problem with Universal analytics when tracking pageView.
Here is the code on the header:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-46738558-1', 'restaurant-mon-repos.fr');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

On the homepage, i have some internal link examples:

http://example.com/homepage

http://example.com/homepage#products

http://example.com/homepage#pricing

http://example.com/homepage#contactus

Before i upgrade to Universal Analytics, It can track all internal links to see which the part is interested with visitors on Google Analytics. But after upgraded to Universal Analytics, it doesn't track internal links! For now, it just tracked the http://example.com/homepage

Anybody have same probem with me? How can i track them automatic or i need to do it manual?
Could you explain details the problem? or maybe i missing the configuration form them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages):

> Note: While the anchor, or hash, portion of the URL is sent to Google
>   Analytics, the value is processed out and will not show up in the page
>   value within the final reports. To preserve the anchor, you must
>   override the default page value.

So it would seem you need to lodge a virtual pageview (presumably) that replaces the hash character with something else.

Personally I would probably try to use an advanced filter on the request url and copy the hash value to a custom dimension (that way both consolidating the url for the reports and retain the ability to track in-page links).

Comment: Thanks for your helps. So, every anchors or has,...should i create a ga("send","pageView", ".#myanchor1")
ga("send","pageView", ".#myanchor2")
ga("send","pageView", ".#myanchor3")